# Android phone does not know its location despite all the sensors being turned on

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

We are facing a very strange problem while fetching device location in Android 2.3 handset. Google Map does not show proper location too. I have turned on Gps, mobile data and agreed to Google terms for the wireless based location calculation.

Rebooting the phone also did not help.

Right now, I have no idea how to make the device location-aware.

Comment: What make/model are you using?

Comment: When you go into Google Maps, does anything appear in the status bar to indicate that it's attempting to access GPS location (in my case, it's a crosshair with a flashing dot inside, which stops flashing once a location has been received). You might also want to try the [GPS Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest) app and see what that tells you.

Comment: I agree with @TreborRude, you should also clear your cache for google maps. Connecting to Wifi can also improve your location accuracy, especially if you are indoors.